# Using Bracket Notation in VisualForce dataTable

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, datatable

Hi all, I am attempting to use bracket notation inside of the value attribute of an `<apex:dataTable>`, but I'm having some issues. The reference works when it's written like so:

```html
<apex:dataTable id="servicesTable" value="{! Contact.RRP_GrantPrograms__r }" var="program" styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

but I receive and Authorization error when written like this:

```html
<apex:dataTable id="servicesTable" value="{! Contact['RRP_GrantPrograms__r'] }" var="program" styleClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
```

Is this notation not possible when retrieving child objects, or is there a way that I could make it work?

My goal is to retrieve all objects with a relationship to Contact and use `<apex:repeat>` to generate a table for them.

**EDIT:** Added error message.

> Authorization Required
>
> You must first log in or register before accessing this page.
> If you have forgotten your password, click Forgot Password to reset it.

**EDIT 2:** Converted the `Force.com Site` to a `Community` and edited the Exception template to show `ErrorDescription` to produce a more informative error.

> Error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.RRP_GrantPrograms__r

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the text of the error message?

Comment: Are you including this page in a `Force.com Site` or a page in a `Community`?

Comment: It's a Force.com site.

Comment: And you checked both syntax options in the site? Or one in your site and one while logged in?

Comment: I apologize, I'm note aware of any syntax options (this is my first project with Salesforce), but it's worth noting that I use bracket notation to reference a key earlier in the page.

Comment: So, I've switched the page over to a `Community`, changed the Exception template, and I'm now receiving a different error.

> Error: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.RRP_GrantPrograms__r

Comment: @AdrianLarson I misunderstood your last comment, but to answer now: I was not logged into the site, but the object was public.